# How to put a string at the front of a file in python

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
>>> p = open(r'/Users/ericxx/Desktop/dest.txt','r+')
>>> xx = p.read()
>>> xx =  xx[:0]+"How many roads must a man walk down\nBefore they call him a man" +xx[0:]
>>> p.writelines(xx)
>>> p.close()
```

the original file content looks like:

How many seas must a white dove sail
Before she sleeps in the sand

---

the result looks like :

How many seas must a white dove sail
Before she sleeps in the sand
How many roads must a man walk down
Before they call him a man
How many seas must a white dove sail
Before she sleeps in the sand

---

expected output :

How many roads must a man walk down
Before they call him a man
How many seas must a white dove sail
Before she sleeps in the sand

Answer (score 5):

You have to "rewind" the file between reading and writing:

```
p.seek(0)
```

The whole code will look like this (with other minor changes):

```
p = open('/Users/ericxx/Desktop/dest.txt','r+')
xx = p.read()
xx = "How many roads must a man walk down\nBefore they call him a man" + xx
p.seek(0)
p.write(xx)
p.close()
```

Comment: It is better to use `with open('/Users/ericxx/Desktop/dest.txt', 'r+') as p:` rather than how you did it

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @messas answer, 
while doing seek to add the data in the front it can also leave you with old data at the end of your file if you ever shortened `xx` at any point.

This is because `p.seek(0)` puts the input pointer in the file at the beginning of the file and any `.write()` operation will overwrite content as it goes. However a shorter content written vs content already in the file will result in som old data being left at the end, not overwritten.

To avoid this you could open and close the file twice with `, 'w')` as the opening parameter the second time around or store/fetch the file contents length and pad your new content. Or truncate the file to your new desired length.

To **truncate** the file, simply add `p.flush()` after you've written the data.

### Also, use the with operator

```
with open('/Users/ericxx/Desktop/dest.txt','r+') as p:
    xx = p.read()
    xx = "How many roads must a man walk down\nBefore they call him a man" + xx
    p.seek(0)
    p.write(xx)
    p.flush()
```

I'm on my phone so apologies if the explanation is some what short and blunt and lacking code. Can update more tomorrow.

Comment: @ericxxcc yw, I added to the example on how to use `r+` and truncating the file to avoid trailing old data. Don't forget to mark this question as answered/solved if you think any of our answers solves your question.